# How do I add a blank row to table using FooTable v3

Tags: javascript, jquery, footable

FooTable v2 allowed users to inject DOM elements - rows into a table - and sorting still kinda works.  FooTable v3 is a complete re-write and the data in the table is completely managed by FooTable.  The original DOM is restructured by FooTable.init.  Adding to the DOM will mean FooTable sorting and filtering will be unaware of the added record.  As far as I can tell, the proper way to add a new row to the FooTable v3 is to call the editing component's function 'addRow'.

The original author of FooTable has assumed many things - such as the developer will want to use a popup asking for values.  In my case, when adding a row I do not want an editor window popping up asking for values.  I merely want to add a blank row to the table programatically/dynamically without using any footable UI components.

How do I call this function?  What is the proper syntax.

I init my table via ...

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.my-footable').footable({
        "editing": {
            "enabled":"true"
        }
    });
});
```

... and I have a click event on a button...

```
$(document).on("click", "#myButton", function (event) {

        var editing = FooTable.get(".my-footable").use(FooTable.Editing);

});
```

... but I am stumped on how to invoke addRow - and what parameters I pass...

Any ideas?

Comment: Checkout step 2d on this page https://fooplugins.github.io/FooTable/docs/examples/component/editing.html

Comment: @RobM. - Thanks for the feedback.  I initially looked at the link you provided too, but step one - Create your editor UI - is what I want to avoid.  My approach is different than the approach by the author.

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  var columns_name = ['id', 'first name', 'last name', 'job title'],
    columns = [],
    rows = [{
      'id': 1,
      'first_name': 'Dennise',
      'last_name': 'Fuhrman',
      'job_title': 'High School History Teacher'
    }];
  /**
    Creating a new object with the help of columns_name array with
    having key title and name and then pushing it to the columns array. We'll
    pass that array in the footable init object.
  */
  for (var i = 0; i < columns_name.length; i++) {
    var column = columns_name[i];
    /**
        In name key replacing spaces with underscore so that it will match with
        the keys in row array of object
    */
    columns.push({
      title: column,
      name: column.replace(/ /g, "_")
    });
  }

  var ft_init_options = {
    columns: columns,
    rows: rows,
    editing: {
      enabled: true,
      alwaysShow: true,
      allowAdd: true,
      allowEdit: false,
      addRow: function() {
        /**
            Creating new row with empty columns having input field
        */
        var values = {
          'id': '<input type="text">',
          'first_name': '<input type="text">',
          'last_name': '<input type="text">',
          'job_title': '<input type="text">'
        }
        ft.rows.add(values);
      },
      deleteRow: function(row) {
        if (confirm('Are you sure you want to delete the row?')) {
          row.delete();
        }
      }
    }
  };

  var ft = FooTable.init('#editing-example', ft_init_options);
});
```

```css
/**
    Remove the following comments if you want to remove the border from the inputs
    and want to display when they are in focus

    */


/**
    textarea:focus, input:focus{
        border-width: 2px;
        border-style: inset;
        border-color: initial;
        border-image: initial;
    }
    textarea, input {
        border : none;
    }

    **/
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://fooplugins.github.io/FooTable/compiled/footable.bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-footable/3.1.6/footable.js"></script>

<div class="container-fluid">
  <hr>
  <h1 class="text-center"> FooTable Editing Example with inputs in row</h1>
  <hr>
  <table id="editing-example" class="table"></table>
</div>
```

If code snippet is not working then have a look on [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/prashantpokhriyal/da13nsdz/)

Comment: thanks for the feedback.  Looking at your answer you are adding a row dynamically before footable init.  I am seeking a way to add a row after footable init.  Or - perhaps you are suggesting always re-init when adding a row?

Comment: I'm not adding row before footable init instead I'm defining what should be done when user will  add a row. So when you will click on Add row button it will call the function defined under addRow which will create new row with input field.

Comment: Oh - sorry - I misread the code.  OK, so do you have an example of calling addRow?

Comment: I've already added code snippet and jsfiddle. Please do have look.

Comment: Thank you @Prashant, your fiddle works as expected by the authors of FooTable.  Like I state in my OP, there are many assumptions by the author of FooTable.  In your example there is no HTML to render the 'New Row' button (Or the delete button for that matter).  I believe FooTable is injecting this DOM element.  Unfortunately this is not where I want the element to be rendered.  As such I cannot use this solution.  I wish there was more separation between the functional behavior and the presentation layer.

Comment: Thank you for coming back. If you see your OP you have written like this **I merely want to add a blank row to the table with <input> controls embedded in the table.** and **I am stumped on how to invoke addRow - and what parameters I pass**. which is exactly what the code does. Maybe you meant to ask something else.

Comment: thank you for the feedback.  I see what you mean.  My question was not exactly clear.  I have edited for clarity.  My question shows I am confused how to call 'addRow'.  Your example does not call addRow, it assumes the solution should use the footable injected DOM elements.